# Result callback of Oauth2 for Github is not called

Tags: ios, swift, github, oauth-2.0

Why is my result callback not called at all when I am trying to authorize with oauth2 for Github?

Here is what I do when my view did appear:

```
    private func login() {
        let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
          consumerKey:    "1e7d92204b39361.....",
          consumerSecret: "6f32158240aca680537c19db010105a3bee.....",
          authorizeUrl:   "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize",
          accessTokenUrl: "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
          responseType:   "code"
        )
        oauthswift.allowMissingStateCheck = true
        oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = SafariURLHandler(viewController: self, oauthSwift: oauthswift)
        guard let rwURL = URL(string: "pl.blueworld.oauth2:/oauth2Callback") else { return }
        oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: rwURL, scope: "repo,gist", state: "") { result in
            print(result)
        }
    }
```

- My App is properly registered as Oauth2 Apps in Github.

[image]

- my Info.plist file is also registered correct way.

[image]

- `application:openUrl` is implemented within `AppDelegate`

  ```
   func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
       OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
       return true
   }
  ```
- using [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) library.

What am I doing wrong?

Permanently get the following:

[image]

Comment: Where is accessTokenUrl?

Comment: I don't know.  I have only used p2.OAuth2 to test authentication with GitHub.

Comment: It worked to my knowledge.  I don't have a sample project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Frankly speaking, based on your 48k rep, is this question some kind of attention test or ...? :)

## Authorization callback URL

[image]

- Your `Info.plist` says `pl.blueworld.oauth2`, but your GitHub application callback URL is `http://gitapp/github_oauth/callback`.

  - Missing `.` (`gitapp` vs `git.app`).
- Your `rwURL` says `pl.blueworld.oauth2:/oauth2Callback`.

  - Missing `/` (`...oauth2:/oauth2...` vs `...oauth2://oauth2...`).
  - Weird case (`C`).

It differs in all those places.

If your intention is to use `http://git.app/github_oauth/callback` (with added `.`) and redirect to `pl.blueworld.oauth2://oauth2Callback`, fine, you can, but the rest still applies.

## Info.plist

I've got `dev-zrzka://oauth-callback` (GH application callback URL). The scheme is `dev-zrzka`. Which is what you should use in the `Info.plist`.

[image]

## Scene delegate

You're handling callback in the `AppDelegate`, but you should use `SceneDelegate` since iOS 13. It's mentioned even in the [README](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift#handle-url-in-appdelegate). That's probably the reason why it isn't called (if we skip the `gitapp` vs `git.app` & redirection problem).

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
            return
        }
        // GH Callback URL dev-zrzka://oauth-callback
        //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if url.host == "oauth-callback" {
            OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
        }
    }
}
```

## View controller

Next problem is that you have to store the `OAuth2Swift` instance somewhere otherwise you'll see `failure(retain)` (from the `print(result)`). All examples in the README says `// create an instance and retain it`.

```swift
import UIKit
import OAuthSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var oauthswift: OAuth2Swift!
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
            consumerKey:    "...", // GH App Client ID
            consumerSecret: "...", // GH App Client Secret
            authorizeUrl:   "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize",
            accessTokenUrl: "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
            responseType:   "token"
        )
        oauthswift.allowMissingStateCheck = true
        oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = SafariURLHandler(viewController: self, oauthSwift: oauthswift)
        guard let rwURL = URL(string: "dev-zrzka://oauth-callback") else { return }
        oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: rwURL, scope: "repo,gist", state: "") { result in
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```